# How to change a radio button's image when another radio button has been clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this table and I want the radio buttons to change images to a check mark, which they do (sort of, but more on that later), and I want whenever I click one of the radio buttons the other radio buttons change into a picture of a X Mark (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX9Q3.png).

Here is my code so far: http://liveweave.com/4poY04.

As you can see no matter which radio button you click the first one always changes to the check mark image. I have tried changing the id of the radio buttons but that only makes the 2nd one always change to the check mark image.

Comment: Could you post the relevant code in the question please?

Comment: Link to the check mark my code uses: http://i.imgur.com/QAUUxYF.jpg.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: @gcampbell That link I gave has all the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is ugly. I only updated your work and now it working.

```js
    function changeImage(id, imgName)
  {
    // reset images
  for (var i = document.getElementsByClassName('theimage').length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('theimage')[i].src = "http://i.imgur.com/DGofFGc.png";
  }
     image = document.getElementById(id);
     image.src = imgName;
  }
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
label > input{ /* HIDE RADIO */
  display:none;
}
label > input + img{ /* IMAGE STYLES */
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><b>B1</b></td>
        <td>
   <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" onClick="changeImage('img1','http://i.imgur.com/QAUUxYF.jpg');">
        <img align="center" name="radio1" class="theimage" id="img1" height="40px" width="40px" src="http://i.imgur.com/DGofFGc.png">
 </input>
   </label>
         </td>
        <td>
   <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" onClick="changeImage('img2','http://i.imgur.com/QAUUxYF.jpg');">
        <img align="center" name="radio2" class="theimage" id="img2" height="40px" width="40px" src="http://i.imgur.com/DGofFGc.png">
 </input>
   </label>
         </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need javascript for this...just use IDs and suitable HTML structured labels attached to the IDs.

Also this has the benefit of being valid HTML.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"] + label {
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(http://www.undergroundwineletter.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/question-mark-red.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/QAUUxYF.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        B1</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender2" value="female">
        <label for="gender2"></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender3" value="other">
        <label for="gender3"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Very nice. Now if I could only find a way to have it with those question marks of mine and then when you click a radio option it turns into basically what you made...

Comment: The edited version is also nice but what I meant is have those question marks originally, than when you click it, it turns into your old version's Check and X marks... But you have already done enough I suppose... Hmmm... I think I might need to add some JS to get what I want... I think I'll have to make it something like this: if radio1 = clicked than change images of radio2 and radio3 to the X mark image, else radio2=clicked than change radio1 and radio3 to the X mark image, else if radio3=clicked than change radio1 and radio3 to the X mark image and etc...

Answer (score -1):

If the wrong checkbox changes, that's because there's a bug in your code.  You have the wrong box tied to the wrong value.

You cannot change the appearance of a packaged control (or "widget," in Linux parlance) other than as permitted by the published API.  You would have to register an event handler that unmanages the checkbox and replaces it with some other control, such as an image or an XmDrawnButton, that shares the same parent AND the same sequential position.  Proper geometry management will ensure that it is managed as a unit with its infracolumnar brethren.